# I have a problem that I could not fetch product details by category

Tags: django, django-views

I have a problem that I could not fetch product details by category
Because Viwes contains two variables and I couldn't get them to show the product details

**Model**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=350, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField( null=False, blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**Urls**

```
path('category/<str:product_category_slug>/<str:product_slug>/', views.product_detail, name="product-detail")
```

**Viwes**

```
def product_detail(request, product_category_slug=None, product_slug=None):
    #How do I get product details through this path that contains a category and then the product
```

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

```
def product_detail(request, product_category_slug, product_slug):
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug, Category__slug=product_category_slug)
    if product:
       return product
    else: 
       return "Product not found"
```

I hope this will return the Project object with the category.
to get Category details lets say you want to get category name and its slug you can just do the following:
category name will `product.Category.name` and slug will be `product.Category.slug`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
def get_product_details(request, category_slug, slug):
    # Change <Category> field name to <category> 
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, category__slug=category_slug, slug=slug)
    context = dict(product=product)
    return response(response, "product_detail.html", context)
```

or this way:

```
def get_product_details(request, category_slug, slug):
     try:
          product = Product._default_manager.get(category__slug=category_slug, slug=slug)
     except Product.DoesNotExist:
          product = None
    context = dict(product=product)
    template_name = "product_404_template.html" if product is None else "product_detail.html"
    return response(response, template_name, context)
```

You still need to handle `404` for both cases.